# Implementing read only accordion using Angular-Bootstrap UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement an Angular Bootsrap-UI accordion that would not allow the user to click to open the accordion.
How do I disable user access? I'll be controlling the opening and closing programmatically.